# How can I use generic type argument inference in another generic type in typescript?

Tags: typescript, generics

I have a function which can accept two arguments:

1. An array of objects with a `value` property.
2. A callback function accepts the array of values from the first argument

This is the sample code:

```
function fn( data, callback ) {
    callback( data.map( x => x.value ) );
}
```

While adding type constrains of typescript, I encountered some problems. Here is the code I tried on typescript playground:

https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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

```js
class Data<T = any> {
    declare value: T;
}

type Modify<T extends unknown[]> = T extends [ first: infer F, ...args: infer U ] ? [ Data<F>, ...Modify<U> ] : [];


type P = Modify<[ 'string', 'number' ]>

// function fn<M>( atom: Data<M>, handler : ( value: M ) => void ): void;
function fn<T extends any[]>( atoms: Modify<T>, handler : ( ...values: T ) => void ): void;
function fn( atoms: Data | Data[], handler: ( ( value: any ) => void ) | ( ( ...values: any[] ) => void ) ): void {

}

// fn( new Data(), () => {} );

fn<[string, number]>( [ new Data<string>(), new Data<number>() ], () => {

} )

fn( [ new Data() ], () => {} )
```

I got an error message on the last line of the code:

```
Argument of type '[Data<any>]' is not assignable to parameter of type '[]'.
  Source has 1 element(s) but target allows only 0.(2345)

input.tsx(13, 10): The call would have succeeded against this implementation, but implementation signatures of overloads are not externally visible.
```

Comment: There's a lot of extra stuff going on in this code I'm not sure how to deal with.  Could you [edit] to resolve these: • Your `Modify` is unnecessarily recursive; you can just use a simple mapped array type like `{[I in keyof T]: Data<T[I]>}`. • What is `P` for? Is it just demonstrating that `Modify` works? If so, could you mention that so it's not just sitting there?

Comment: (See prev comment) Once you fix that, I'm *guessing* your problem is that TS infers `T` from both arguments to `fn` and you don't want it to infer from `handler`. You can suppress that with `NoInfer` as shown [here](https://tsplay.dev/wQjkAN). I'm not sure if that's what you want (I don't see a description of the intended behavior, other than a lack of compiler error). If it is what you want I could write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: Thanks. Would you mind please [edit]ing the question as I asked and then I'll write up an actual answer? (My comments here don't constitute an answer, just requests for clarification and confirmation before I write one).